# Firebase Crashlytics integration stucked at 'We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers.' iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I m trying to integrate Crashlytics, I have integrated earlier also. In sample project which I created to test it, in that it works fine. but in my actual project it stucks at step 3 "We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers."

I have followed all steps including run script

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

Also tried changing Debug information formate to DWARF with DSYM file. But nothing is working. This all is works if I integrate in sample app.

Bellow is the pod file list I m using in my project.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. I m stucked here from 2 days.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do

  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'TPKeyboardAvoidingSwift'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 9.0.0'
  pod 'STPopup'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'STRatingControl'
  pod 'Hero'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar'
  pod 'GIFProgressHUD'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.2.0'
  pod 'GPUImage'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'


  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Why are you using Crashlitycs? It will be shutted down on May 4, 2020

Comment: No Fabric is going to shut down, and it is mentioned in google docs that we need to use it as fabric is going to be replaced by firebase crashlytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1&platform=ios

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is a migrated app since you are using Fabric dependencies. Your app either did not send a build and run event or it got stuck in an inactive state in the pipeline. If you are using Xcode to test this, I recommend launching your app, closing it, and then opening it from the actual virtual device dashboard. This will make sure that a build and run event is being properly sent to the endpoint.

However, if my above suggestion does not work, then you will need to write in to support(at)fabric(dot)io so they can ask for your AppDelegate init statements and info.plist to confirm what the issue might be.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Kodysh, I tried your solution but its not working. I think I need to write to support now

Comment: how did you solved this issue? I am having same issue too.

Comment: Have you tried causing a test crash and seeing if that helps? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation)

Comment: How did you solved this issue ?I am also having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and more research and tried then solved this issue.

Please follow the below steps to successfully configure Firebase Crashlytics.

1. Uninstall Crashlystics pods like  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
2. Remove run script from build settings
3. Remove Projects from Firebase consoles
4. Create new projects on firebase consoles
5. Configures setups like project name, Bundle ID, etc
6. make sure the bundle id in small laters even your Xcode camelcase for example your bundle id com.DemoFirebase.app then you need set in firebase configure com.demofirebase.app
7. Add pod 'Firebase/Analytics' in pod file
8. Execute  script pod install in the command
9. Clean, Build and run the project it will communicate with firebase
10. Add FirebaseApp.configure() in appdelegate.swift
11. Clean, Build and run the project it will communicate with firebase
12. Add pods like pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
13. Add the new Run script in build settings
14. Clean, Build and run the project it will communicate with firebase
15. Enable Crashlystics on the Firebase dashboard
16. Test dummy crash using this code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=4
17. Congrats your Crashlystics successfully configures

I hope the above steps will help in your project and reduce more researching times

Thanks and Hits on the vote button

Happy Codings!